# Different results for same code

Tags: tcl

Why this two piece of code outputs are different?

```
set j 0.0981747704247
set i 0.0981747704247
for { ; } { $i <= 25} {set i [expr {$i + $j}]} {
    puts "i = $i"
}
```

```
set j 0.0981747704247
set i 0.0981747704247
for {; } { $i <= 25 } {set i [expr $i + $j]} {
    puts "i = $i"
}
```

Comment: I have tcl 8.5.13, and the results are identical.

Comment: How about telling us what the difference is? This is not hide-and-go-seek.

Comment: @andy Floats and unbraced expressions? Pretty easy to guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Prior to 8.5,** the results of those two evaluations could well be different. With the braced expression, those fractional values would be kept as IEEE double precision floating point numbers, whereas with the *unbraced* expression the values would be converted to string (using 15 decimal digits of precision by default) and then converted back again. It's those conversions that cause the value changes.

**Starting in Tcl 8.5,** the double precision floating point serialization engine was changed so that it instead serializes to the *shortest possible* string representation that will be deserialized back to the identical IEEE double. This means that those two scripts — differing in just whether things are braced — behave the same once more, closing a subtle semantic hole.

But you should still brace your expressions, as then Tcl can actively use efficient processing for handling your code. It also means that — because you've got no recompilation of expressions — you can never have problems with a stray “`[file delete -force "/"]`” or other such odd user input (as it will be just “not a valid number” rather than “piece of script”).

Answer (score 1):

The output should be the same. However, the process time will definitely be different. The unbraced expression in `eval` will make the function take more time to evaluate, while the braced expression there will be about 80% faster. You can read more on the [wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225).

You'll also find some instances where brackets are better left out as well, and how using or not using brackets alters the result of expressions which might look the same.